# Reaching variables that is not created with 'this' keyword in constructor in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im looking for how to reach the variables inside a constructor without using 'this' keyword. If I put this in front of the variables, everything works fine.

```
function MyQueue() {
    this.collection = [];
    this.index = 0;
}

MyQueue.prototype.isEmpty = function () {
    return this.collection.length === 0;
}
```

However, if I remove this keyword, I can't reach collection and index when I create an object. Is there any way to reach these variables?

```
function MyQueue ()
{
     let collection = [];
     let index = 0;
}


MyQueue.prototype.isEmpty = function()
{
   return this.collection.length === 0; 
}
```

This one doesn't work. How can I reach the collection and index inside a constructor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if thats possible, as the `this` keyword is require to bind attributes to the function in order for them to be accessible in any prototype you create via the function. variables declared with `let` are not binded to the function, they are only local to it.

Comment: no, once (local - e.g. `let`, `var`, `const`) variable value is not assigned to some "outer" variable(`this`, variable from outer scope or global variable) it will be lost after appriate block(or function in case of `var` variable) is finished. But what is your goal? Why do you need that at all? Let's work on goal itself!

Comment: Why you don't want to use `this`? You want `collection` to be independent from `MyQueue` instance?

Comment: Those are properties, not variables, and yes you have to use `this` for them.

Comment: Thank you for answers, I'm new at Javascript, therefore just trying to get ideas what really 'this' do.

Comment: Here's a good article which I believe explains how it can be done by example https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-are-some-practical-javascript-objects-that-have-encapsulation-fc4c1a79c655 . There's even a queue implementation, with proper private vars and public accessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I put this in front of the variables, everything works fine.

In this scenario, you are adding properties to the queue object. Anything that has a reference to that object will also be able to get to its properties

> However, if I remove the this keyword, I can't reach collection and index when I create a object.

In this case, you are creating local variables. They will only be in scope to code in the current function, as well as any nested functions.

> Is there any way to reach these variables?

Only inside the constructor and any nested functions. By nested functions, i mean you could do this if you wanted:

```js
    function MyQueue () {
      let localVariable = 3;
      this.logLocalVariable = function() {
        console.log(localVariable);
      }
    }

    const queue = new MyQueue();
    queue.logLocalVariable(); // logs 3;
    console.log(queue.localVariable) // logs undefined
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicholas Tower sir, really good explanation.